# Can I create a macOS application with Objective-C language with Flutter Desktop?

Tags: flutter

Seems the flutter create command will support language-choosing only for iOS&Android .
with

`flutter create -i objc`

If I want to create an **application run in macOS** ,and develop it in Objective-C , anyway to do it？